# Count number of files using unix

Tags: bash

How can we count the number of files present in a directory at server using unix in mainframe environment. I have tried the following commands but it abending with error mentioned at bottom:

cd "/Deepak/dir"

```
ls -1 | wc -l
ls -l . | egrep -c '^-'
ls -cf
```

After trying first command, the error message I am getting is:
Can't ls: "/Deepak/dir/|" not found.

I don't know why pipe is shown here. And I think that is the reason, error is saying directory is not found as "/Deepak/dir/|" and "/Deepak/dir/" are not same.

Comment: What do you mean, "using unix in a mainframe environment"?  Would you be specific about the UNIX flavor you're on?  And also, when you say they're "not working", what do you mean?  Please show the exact error message.  Finally, your command is probably wrong above (which may explain your errors): `ls | wc -1` should be `ls | wc -l` (dash ell, not dash one).

Comment: I tried by correcting 1 by l also. I have mentioned the exact error. I am getting pipe symbol after directory name.

Comment: Well, that error says it all: the directory `/Deepak/dir` does not exist.  However, the way that error is worded suggests you are doing `ls /Deepak/dir`.  Please cut and paste the exact command and error in one block.  And as requested in my previous comment: what UNIX flavor are you on?  The output of `uname -a` will help.

Comment: @bishop: I tried to find version of unix by command "uname -a", but its telling...this is invalid. And I have mentioned exact error above that I am getting.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`ls -1 | wc -l`

This appears to work for me.

Comment: Bad idea! This will count directories and named pipes as well... and files with newlines in their names twice.

Comment: @SLoW I dont know why this is not working in my flavour of unix. Is there any way to find unix flavour. I tried uname -a, but this also is not working.

Comment: @SLoW: I am getting exact error:Can't ls: "/Deepak/dir/|" not found. Can you please help why Here pipe symbol is coming. As soon I find unix version, I will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

ls | wc -l will also work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want only files and not (sub)directories to be counted in the directory you are checking use the following instead of ls -1

```
find yourdirname -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

`-maxdepth` limits `find` to yourdirname only and `-type f` takes into account files only when searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want files only AND you only want to count files with newlines in their names once, then this should be a reasonably safe method:

```
i=0
while read -d ''; do
    ((i++))
done < <( find /Deepak/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 )
echo $i
```

*Caveat:  The GNU version of `find` found in most [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) distros is subtly different to the [bsd](/questions/tagged/bsd) `find`, which is probably more likely found in "Unix".  The above works for me with both versions (e.g. on Linux and OSX).  But your [mainframe](/questions/tagged/mainframe) may have yet another different version of `find`.*